# How to add and display images in subcategory Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento and have a few obstacles, maybe someone can handle it here, I want to customize the appearance of my subcategory to be like the following picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/byLBg.png

Please help. Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You should add exactly each image for each child produc. Then go in **file etc/view.xml** in the theme which you are using, you need to fix this command:

from:

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
   <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">prepend</var>
</vars>
```

to:

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
   <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

After that, clear cache.